# SELECT value BEFORE max mysql

Tags: mysql, database

so, i have this table generated annually :

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | 20162|
|  2 | 20162|
|  3 | 20171|
|  4 | 20171|<<<||| "how do i get this bfore max value"
|  5 | 20172| 
|  6 | 20172|
+----+------+
```

If i query :

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE where name=(SELECT max(name))
```

The result is **20172**

How do i get the value before that (20171)?

Comment: You want second max value?

Comment: second highest? yes

Comment: use where name in (Select) or try using join query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the little trick:

```
SELECT name FROM table ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

If you want a portable solution (since the above will only work in MySQL probably):

```
SELECT name FROM table t1 where 
    1 = (SELECT count(distinct name) 
        from table t2 
        where t2.name > t1.name )
```

This selects the name which has exactly one other name which is greater than it. It will have issues when e.g. all values are the same but that may actually be the intention sometimes.

Comment: You Can do it like fetching 2 max element the same way like we do in getting  2nd highest salary query.

Comment: @www.cahyonegoro.com actually for your task the 2nd code would probably work. The first one gets the second row regardless. For the first one to work you'd need to `GROUP BY name`.

Answer (score 1):

This will get second max.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
    WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT MAX(name) FROM table ) 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: you have `WHERE where` , please update your answer @MuhammadSaqlain

Comment: @MohaMad Done. Thanks.

Comment: It was better to keep old code beside this new one, friends!

Comment: Stack didn't even confirmed me before changing.

Comment: It was just because of his reputation and administrator levels ! I tried to recover your original code

Comment: @MohaMad The OP is very specific about which row they want returned.

Comment: You're right and my comment is absolutely wrong! i'm going to delete last comments and don't be disturber, thanks for your response. @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this:

```
SELECT name
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM yourtable) TMP
ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
select b.second_id,b.name from
(select id, max(name) as max from tbl_max) as a
LEFT JOIN
(select  id as second_id, name from tbl_max ) as b  
on a.id <> second_id where name < a.max  order by name desc limit 1;
```

Another solution much better:

```
set @max= 0;
select max(name) into @max from tbl_max;
select * from tbl_max where name < @max ORDER BY id desc limit 1
```

it return a result of

> 4 20171

Comment: you can merge two first lines in second query block: `SELECT @max := MAX(name) FRM tablename ; `

Answer (score 0):

If you want Max(name)

```
SELECT id,MAX(name) FROM table
WHERE name < (SELECT MAX(name) FROM table )
```

or

```
SELECT id,MAX(name) FROM table
WHERE name <> (SELECT MAX(name) FROM table )
```

And there is an article for [Find nth high value](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/find-nth-highest-salary-sql/)

---

(*as Question changed later, this tricks is not useful for **this problem***)

can you use this simple `order by` ?

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
group by name
order by name desc
limit 1,1
```

if you have multiple equal values in MAX(name) you need `group by`, even this query is not general solution!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 1,1;
```

The `LIMIT` clause accepts two values, an offset and a count. When only 1 value is provided, it assumes the offset is 0

`DISTINCT` is necessary as you have duplicate values for name. If this was unintentional, it's not needed.

Example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea6e2/2

Comment: Plainly,this will not return the desired result

Comment: desired results changed by the Time!! @Strawberry

Comment: I see. Well, it happens like that sometimes

Comment: So down votes for this Question-side changes is not necessary! @Strawberry

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code.It will give you nth highest record.

```
SELECT NAME FROM table ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT n,1
```

Hope this will helps